# Number of machine instructions for an llvm PHINode on x86/amd64

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

I'm currently writting a pass in `opt` that happens to create extra control flow and, as a result of that, I need to also insert a lot of `llvm::PHINode` instructions. The endgame of my pass is to reduce codesize and, as far I can tell, the number of `llvm` instructions after I run it is lower. However, in most cases I don't see a significant reduction in code size, or sometimes I even see an increase (even though the total number of `llvm` is smaller). I've been trying to find a reference to how `PHINode` instructions are implemented on `x86/amd64` but without luck. The obvious solution for me would be to just go through the source and find out myself but I can't invest that much time in investigating this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.